# In Gmail, is there a way to temporarily bounce back all incoming mail (SMTP 550 User Unknown)?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure Gmail so that filtered user gets an NDR (non-deliverable receipt) or “bounce” message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/how-to-configure-gmail-so-that-filtered-user-gets-an-ndr-non-deliverable-receip)

I have a gmail account I would like to keep in the long-term. But in the short-term, I want all incoming mail to bounce (SMTP 550 code, "User Unknown") so as to deter spammers.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this a regular @gmail.com account or is it a Google Apps (your own domain name) Gmail account?

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is [greylisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting).  Greylisting does exactly what you are talking about, temporarily refuse email so the spammers have to spend more time trying to send to you.

Comment: That is useful to know, but you didn't answer his question.

Comment: his question was about detering spammers, 550 doesn't deter spammers, which is why I answered his question the way I did.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Jim B, you have a point: Good answers contain sound advice. But good answers also must explictly answer the question, in the first sentence, even when the answer is "You're doing it wrong". It may take an extra minute to rephrase your answer, but it really improves the quality of SA/SF. There's a good discussion on Meta (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18552/answer-whats-asked-or-answer-whats-desired), and I'd also recommend reading http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx for a well-reasoned opinion.

Comment: I think this falls into the glass bottle or old shoe type question see http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx

I don't want to get too "meta" here but it seems pointless to spend time explaining how to perform a task that will not actually do what the poster is asking about.  I can (and probably will) roll my comment into my answer but since the question isn't " how do I bounce all email" but is instead "how do I bounce all email to deter spammers" since greylisting accompishes exactly that (bounces all email to deter spammers) I thought it a good fit.